# Call to undefined method App\Models\Employee::assignRole()

Tags: laravel, permissions, laravel-8, roles

I want to assign role to employee when add the new employee but it always show this error - Call to undefined method App\Models\Employee::assignRole().What should I do to solve this problem?

This is the code at the EmployeeController store function().

```
$employee = new Employee;
        $employee->first_name=$request->first_name;
        $employee->last_name=$request->last_name;
        $employee->username=$request->username;
        $employee->email=$request->email;
        $employee->employee_id=$request->employee_id;
        $employee->pass=bcrypt($request->pass);
       
        $employee->phone=$request->phone;
        $employee->company_id=$request->company_id;
        $employee->department_id=$request->department_id;
        $employee->designation_id=$request->designation_id;
      
        $employee->save();

        $employee->assignRole($request->role);
       
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Employee Added');
```

The blade code

```
     <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="grid grid-rows-2">
                                    <label for="role">Role</label>
                                    <select id="role" name="role" class="form-control  border p-2"
                                        placeholder="Enter Role">
                                        @foreach (['Admin','User'] as $item)
                                            <option value="{{$item }}">
                                                {{$item }}
                                         
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

I have put the hasRoles at User.php

```
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;



class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;
```

Comment: add in Model Employee
 public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

Comment: @Abdulmajeed
 added but still same error

Comment: You added `use HasRoles` to the `User` model. If you want to access those methods on the `Employee` model, wouldn't you need to add it to the `Employee` model? — unless `Employee` extends `User`.

Comment: @ matticustard
 can already!!!! Thank you!!!